# Replace the first word in a line with another word using shell

Tags: shell

In my file(file1.txt), I have one line where I need to replace the first word with another one.

```
centralbank=14.4.0.4.SAMPLE=xyz/plugins/centralbank/patch144004
```

If you see the above line you can see that `centralbank` is repeating in that line. I want to replace the first `centralbank` with `Central Bank Int'l corp`.

My output should be like

```
Central Bank Int'l corp=14.4.0.4.SAMPLE=xyz/plugins/clientpatch/centralbank/patch144004
```

I tried the below command. But, because of the single quotes in `Cental Bank Int'l Corp` it is not giving

me the output I want

```
 cat file1.txt | awk '{sub(/centralbank/,"Central Bank Int'l Corp")}1'
```

Can Someone please help me with this. Helps will be appreciated

Comment: To insert single-quote inside single-quoted shell string, you can use `'"'"'` (eg. `'Int'"'"'l'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed` without `g` (global) flag:

```
s='centralbank=14.4.0.4.SAMPLE=xyz/plugins/centralbank/patch144004'
sed "s/centralbank/Central Bank Int'l corp/" <<< "$s"
```

```
Central Bank Int'l corp=14.4.0.4.SAMPLE=xyz/plugins/centralbank/patch144004
```

Using same concept in `awk`:

```
awk -v r="Central Bank Int'l corp" '{sub(/centralbank/, r)} 1' <<< "$s"
```

```
Central Bank Int'l corp=14.4.0.4.SAMPLE=xyz/plugins/centralbank/patch144004
```

Comment: Hii Anubhava. Thanks for the quick response. Your command is giving me the output as I wanted.